# How to String.replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//sg, "")

Tags: regex, string, replace, haxe, openfl

In AS3 I could use String.replace as follows:

```
JSON.parse(String(new JSON_CONTROLLERS()).replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//sg, ""));
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Haxe/OpenFL?

If not, what are my options?

For anyone that wants to see what the input and output would be in AS3:
Input: http://pastebin.com/raw/B0LD2gyg (contents of controllers.json)
Output: http://pastebin.com/raw/qJgCLz9f

The closest I have got is this:

```
var jsonControllers:String;
jsonControllers = new JSON_CONTROLLERS().toString();
jsonControllers = StringTools.replace(jsonControllers, "/", "");
```

The application is just showing a black screen, with no errors (FPS is still updating and displaying correctly, nothing else, so I know it did not crash at least).
I was hoping this would work, then call StringTools.replace() several more times until I cut out all of the characters.

Note: The mentions of JSON are relative to my end goal, not exactly the issue of the topic, I left it in **hoping someone will try and reproduce my output using the input 'pastebin' I provided** with JSON parsing in mind.

**How would I also remove text in-between /* *text here* */?**

Extra Reference(s):

```
@:file("assets/controllers.json")
class JSON_CONTROLLERS extends openfl.utils.ByteArray.ByteArrayData {}

class Input { ...
```

Thank you

Comment: If the answer posted below is **working** then please mark it as as **SOLVED** (click the tick mark next to Answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look at Haxe standard [Replace](https://haxe.org/manual/std-regex-replace.html)?

Comment: I actually did before I posted this, but I didn't understand the examples - What is ~/ or ~/b? - does /g mean replace all? Why is there a slash before the 'g', it doesn't explain that. Why $1, why not $2? Why is there a '+'? I'm not at the skill level to make sense of these *cryptic* examples.

Comment: Try to do like in your example
`var r = ~/\/\*.*?\*\//sg;`
`jsonControllers.replace(r, ""));`

Comment: I don't seem to have a replace function under the class type String; And for StringTools.replace, it errors with: should be String not Ereg.

Comment: Sorry, my typing error 
`var r = ~/\/\*.*?\*\//sg;`
`r.replace(jsonControllers, ""));`

Comment: This works, unfortunately I do not understand how the magic is happening, do you know of a more in-depth explanation of "~/\/\*.*?\*\//sg" and why it's auto-assigned to Ereg? I would prefer to learn something than just to walk away with the answer. Thank you

Comment: You could read more in [Regular Expressions docs](https://haxe.org/manual/std-regex.html). Concerning auto-assigning: [_The explicit type annotations are not required in Haxe, because the compiler can infer the type_](https://haxe.org/manual/types.html)